# How can I reduce the build time for an ASP.Net application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET 4.0.  If I need to run my project I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and then wait for the SQL Server to run, and then wait for the browser window to open. It really takes along time which is exhaustive especially when it is about debugging.

I understand that when modifying only the design page you can directly refresh your browser to see the changes, but when the modification is on the code behind I am obliged to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> every time.  Are there any other best practices to reduce this amount of time?

Comment: What do you want without compiling you want changes in application?

Comment: i need changes in code behind to take place without waiting alot,

Comment: You have to recompile the code every time if you made any change in the code behind. There is no such way. And one more point sql-server instance keep running you don't need to run it.

Comment: so, i am already using the best practice ?!

Comment: Yes. you are using the right way.

Comment: look man, suppose i have two lists of objects, one of them is a subset of the another. i want to loop through the small one and delete each common item between the small and the big, thus the result will be the big list with only uncommon items.
does this approach work man?
foreach(var x in small)big.remove(x) ??

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ reply my last quesion please..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recompile code every time you change the code. However, in case you have a solution with many projects, you can limit the projects to be recompiled from the *Build Configuration Manager*. This way you will reduce the time of the build process before your application runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have symbols turned on (in VS Tools | Options | Debugging | Symbols) this can add quite a bit of time to debugging builds.  You may want to consider turning it off and only re-enabling it when you need to.